# using multiple waitKey() in an if-elif test, second key test always fails, even when that key is pressed

Tags: python, opencv

I made a simple code to take snapshots from my webcam when prompted by pressing 's', and quit if I pressed 'q'. Code runs fine but the elif statement for the quitting part alone is ignored.

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
counter = 0

while(True):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow('Webcam', frame)
    if  (cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF) == ord('s'):
        print("s working")
        counter = counter + 1
        cv2.imwrite("Snapshot_" + str(counter) + ".png", frame)
    elif (cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF) == ord('q'):
        print("q working")
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I also tried swapping their order, the if statement being the 'q' condition and the elif being 's', the second statement is always the one skipped.
Update: it only works if I hold q for a while
Why isn't it working normally?

Comment: Because each time you are waiting for another key press. So first you are waiting for some key, check if it is `s`, then you wait for another, check if it is `q` and so on.

Comment: as @matszwecja said, waitKey is blocking.  You need to capture it at the top, and then compare the results to your keys.

Comment: If you save the keypress value in a variable before the conditions and then check on that variable instead, it should work.

Comment: The issue with your code is that the elif statement for the 'q' key is only being checked after the cv2.imshow() function is called. The cv2.waitKey() function is used to check for key presses, but it is only being used in the 's' key press check. To fix this, you need to move the 'q' key press check to the same location as the 's' key press check, before the cv2.imshow() function. This way, the 'q' key press check will be performed before the webcam frame is displayed and the loop continues.

Comment: Your logic seems a bit strange. You first wait one second and if key pressed is "s" then you do stuff, and after that one second you wait another second and if if key pressed is "q", then do stuff. You probably want to  use waitKey without a delay.

Comment: That fixed it. I put waitKey in a variable and used that in the conditions instead, now it works. Thanks everyone.

Comment: @saquintes it's blocking for about a millisecond, which isn't worthy of the label "blocking". the issue is that any key event would quickly have been consumed by the first call, and the second has nothing to work with.

Comment: @Itération122442 that's not seconds, that's milliseconds, approximately. the single issue is expecting multiple waitKey() calls to return the code for the same event, instead of an event having been consumed by each call.

Answer (score 0):

As I learned from the comments, the problem was caused by the waitKey delay. So to fix it I put the pressed button in a variable and compared the condition statements to that variable instead.

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
counter = 0

while(True):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow('Webcam', frame)
    k = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
    if  k == ord('s'):
        print("s working")
        counter = counter + 1
        cv2.imwrite("Screenshot_" + str(counter) + ".png", frame)
    elif k == ord('q'):
        print("q working")
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is *not* caused by any delays, nor by any blocking.

After `cap.read()` returns a new frame, there may be key events waiting because you pressed some keys.

Each `waitKey()` consumes one key press event and returns it, if there was a key event.

If you pressed a key, the first `waitKey()` receives that event, and if it was the wrong key, the `if` doesn't run its consequent code.

Then, the second `waitKey()` has no key event to handle, so it returns -1.

If you *held the key down*, you might have had a chance to create enough key press events to get one of them into the second `waitKey()`.

The **proper solution** is to call `waitKey()` **once per loop**, and store its returned value in a variable.

Then you test that variable against as many key codes as you like.

```
while True:
    ...
    keycode = cv.waitKey()
    if keycode == ord('s'):
        ...
    elif keycode == ord('q'):
        ...
```

That `&0xFF` stuff is **superfluous** and outdated since 2016. `waitKey()` does that already. It is superfluous.